# How can I create new variables within a loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a form and I want to retrieve the values by their id's. Instead of writing var itemnamehere = document.getElementById('theid'); multiple times, I want to be able to loop through the inputs in the form and create variables within a for loop.

This is what I have so far

```
var gsItems = document.getElementsByClassName('gsinput').getAttribute('id');

    for(var i = 0; i < gsItems.length; i++){

        //create new variable here

    }
```

Comment: how are you going to use them? would an array work?

Comment: Is there an easier solution than to type out a new variable for each of them?

Comment: an array would be one way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Because `getElementsByCLassName` returns an nodelist you can't use `getAttribute` on it because that method is reserved for single elements only. BUT you also don't need the id either if I understand your question. You can simply iterate over the nodelist you get with `getElementsByCLassName` and do whatever you need to with the inputs, like grab their values.

Here's how you might approach it with ES6:

```js
const gsItems = document.getElementsByClassName('gsinput');

[...gsItems].forEach(item => {
  console.log(item.value);
});
```

```html
<input class="gsinput" value="1" />
<input class="gsinput" value="2" />
<input class="gsinput" value="3" />
<input class="gsinput" value="4" />
<input class="gsinput" value="5" />
```

If you wanted to use ids you might want to create a map of ids against values. You could do something like this with [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const gsItems = document.getElementsByClassName('gsinput');

const obj = [...gsItems].reduce((obj, item) => {
  obj[item.id] = item.value;
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<input class="gsinput" id="steve" value="1" />
<input class="gsinput" id="daisy" value="2" />
<input class="gsinput" id="tina" value="3" />
<input class="gsinput" id="dennis" value="4" />
<input class="gsinput" id="bob" value="5" />
```

And here's the ES5 method:

```js
const gsItems = document.getElementsByClassName('gsinput');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(gsItems, function (item) {
  console.log(item.value);
});
```

```html
<input class="gsinput" value="1" />
<input class="gsinput" value="2" />
<input class="gsinput" value="3" />
<input class="gsinput" value="4" />
<input class="gsinput" value="5" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Id is not perfect approach to get  multiple form input values when using a loop.

```
function getSubmitValue(params) {
        var formObject = document.theForm;
        var itemnamehere = [];
        if (formObject.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < formObject.length; i++) {
                if (formObject[i].value !== "") {
                    itemnamehere.push(formObject[i].value);
                }
            }
        } else {
            alert("Please check your form input value")
        } 
    }



<form id="myForm" name="theForm">
    <input type="text" name="user" id="user" value="Arsalan" />
    <input type="text" name="occopation" id="occopation" value="doctor" />
    <input type="number" name="age" id="age" value="27" />
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="johndoe@test.com" />
    <textarea name="message" id="message">Enter Your Message Her</textarea>
    <button type="submit" onClick="getSubmitValue()">Place Order</button>
</form>
```